# Jquery MultiDatesPicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-multidatespicker

I need a jquery date picker with some custom modifications. I use MultiDatesPicker v1.6.1 for my task as it provide facility to select multiple dates. But according to my requirements, user should able to select days of a week  (ex.. SUNDAY/ MONDAY) and all dates under those day and current month should highlight and take for further process as an array or list.

Comment: So - what do you want to ask the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with eyecon datepicker where you can select the multiples dates and allows to customize the dates to pick
[Check this](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/)